# Controller required via $stateProvider not binding data to $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I got a $stateProvider in my app with which i'm requiring a controller like below,

```
$stateProvider
.state('randomState', {
  url: "/randomState",
  templateUrl: "template.html",
  controller: require('randomData')
});
```

the template.html is very simple that it has the below markup,

```
<simple-table data="tableData.data"></simple-table>
```

All i do in the controller is using the $http service, i hit an end point which provides me a JSON object and once the data is received, in the success callback i attach the $scope as `$scope.tableData = data`, but in the page i could see the `<tr>`'s getting populated but not the cells `<td>`, could not see any errors in the console, also when i log `$scope.tableData` i could see the proper object getting binded, any idea on why it is not binding the data's inside cell element.

I even tried encapsulating the $http service inside $timeout, but no luck. JSON response would look something like below,

```
{
"data": {
  "columns": [
    {"header": "Column header"},
    {"header": "Column header"}
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "Row Header <br>(optional)",
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
      "$7.50B",
      "427,576,608",
      "$7.50B"
    ],[
      "Row Header",
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
      "45.06",
      "+24.54%",
      "45.06"
    ]
  ]
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Comment: $http({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: '/someURL', //to fetch data  
    }).success(function(data){  
        $scope.tableData = data;  

    }).error(function(err){  
        console.log(err);  
    });